# URL rewrite subdomain to GET

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite

> www.domain.com?player=playersName&server=serverName

OR

> domain.com?player=playersName&server=serverName

To

> www.serverName.domain.com?player=playersName

OR

> serverName.domain.com?player=playersName

with URL rewrite in .htaccess file.

Thank you very much in advance!
Rob

Comment: Are `domain.com` and `servername.domain.com` pointing to the same document root folder on the same server ?

Comment: Yes, they are pointing to the same folder